# Cursor Adapter with multi select

Tags: android

I've written an APP the uses has a small SQL lite DB and using a cursor adapter I can retrieve the records and populate a list view with them. from there I can get the Id of a selected item and delete it from the DB which works great. the issue I have is that as the DB grows deleting one row at a time would be slow and frustrating so I wanted to know if there was any way to allow multiple selections possibly with check boxes or by even changing the text color of the items selected so that I can retreiving their relative ID's.

I have read some posts that talk about custom cursor adapters but I am not sure how to adapt them to my code. I have posted my code below.

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] {DBHelper.KEY_FIELD0, 
                            DBHelper.KEY_FIELD1,
                            DBHelper.KEY_FIELD2,
                            DBHelper.KEY_FIELD3,
                            DBHelper.KEY_FIELD4};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text,R.id.text2,R.id.text3,R.id.text4,R.id.text5};
    SimpleCursorAdapter dblist = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c, from, to);                                                                                               
    setListAdapter(dblist);   
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done that myself but I did find this tutorial that explains how to add check boxes to a list:

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-multiple-choice-example/

You can use that example to allow multipe selection of items in a list control.  Instead of using the array array adaptor as in this example instead use your `SimplecursorAdapter`.  The only gotcha you will have to work out is that the example uses `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` for the list entries and you need to replace that with your layout since you obviously want a few more than one text field.

I'm not at home so I cannot try it out but I did find this:
http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg21920.html

which seems to refer to making your own multiple_choice layout for a list item.

After the user has made their choices you can remove multiple records at one time by running SQL in your database adaptor:

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE _id IN (1, 3, 6, 7)
```

where the list of numbers are the selected id values.

Comment: Ian, Thanks very much for this I will get to work integrating it into my existing code. I'm pretty new to android and SQLite I wonder if I might pose a another question about something that should be simple but will not work for me. I want to run a simple select count against the database and be able to pass the resulting number to a text view.

Comment: I have created my custom layout to display all the fields and added a check box, but I have lost the ability to select an item and capture it's id. I can check/ un check the check box.

Comment: I found that the way around this is to set the checkbox's focusable attribute to false and that allows the item selections again.

Comment: OK so I have got the multi choice working on my list view - I'm not using checkboxes i'm just passing the item id's from the adapter to a list. but i am going mad trying to figure out how to get a count from the database - I have tried a raw query and also using the android method in the database class, but the App keeps crashing when i call the method.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly you want get the result of something like "SELECT count(Country) FROM country" and display that number in a view.  I think that warrants a separate question - I personally have not done that yet (I am also new to Android). My guess would be that using SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery would give you cursor with one row and one column then call getInt with the first column.

Comment: I had thought this warranted another question,I want a simple select as you have described, I have tried raw query but it crashes when I call it. I will try again after more research perhaps I have done something wrong and if I still have no luck I will post another question. thank for your help.